# Access the data inside 2 arrays

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm using trying load data which is inside 2 arrays. At the moment I have successfully loaded items array within array. When I try to access the data inside last array it doesn't load.

I have this array from json response

```
{  
      "Category":"1PI",
      "Description":"Chicken Bacon",
            "MainCategoryID":1,
      "MenuDescription":"Menu Description ",
      "SubMenuEntity":[  
         {  
            "Crust":"Sausage",
            "Description":"Sausage Crust Large",
            "ExtraItemEntity":[  
               {  
                  "Description":"Add BBQ Chicken-120.00",
```

2nd array starts with SubMenuEntity, I have loaded that. I want to load the data Description which is inside the array ExtraItemEntity. How can I achieve that?
This is the android code to data inside array inside array.

```
    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            List<String> crust = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> extraDescription = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
                        && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1")) {

                    JSONArray subMenuArray = object.getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");
                    for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
                        JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray
                                .getJSONObject(j);
                        Log.i("Crust", subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));
                        crust.add(subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));

                        Log.i("Description", subMenuObject.getString("Description"));
                        description.add(subMenuObject.getString("Description"));
                    }

//                  JSONArray ExtraItemEntity = object.getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity");
//                  for (int j = 0; j < ExtraItemEntity.length(); ++j) {
//                      JSONObject extraItemEntityObject = ExtraItemEntity
//                              .getJSONObject(j);
//                      Log.i("Description", extraItemEntityObject.getString("Description"));
//                      extraDescription.add(extraItemEntityObject.getString("Description"));
//                  }

                }
                crustSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_crust);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterCru = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, crust);
                dataAdapterCru
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                crustSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterCru);

                sizeSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_pizza_size);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterDes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, description);
                dataAdapterDes
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sizeSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterDes);

//              extraDescriptionOneSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_extratoppingone);
//              ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterExtraDesOne = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//                      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, extraDescription);
//              dataAdapterExtraDesOne
//              .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//              extraDescriptionOneSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterExtraDesOne);
//              
//              extraDescriptionTwoSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_extratoppingtwo);
//              ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterExtraDesTwo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//                      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, extraDescription);
//              dataAdapterExtraDesTwo
//              .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//              extraDescriptionTwoSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterExtraDesTwo);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Updated code**

```
@Override
public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

    try {
        List<String> crust = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> extraDescription = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

            if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
                    && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1")) {

                JSONArray subMenuArray = object.getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");
                for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
                    JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray
                            .getJSONObject(j);
                    Log.i("Crust", subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));
                    crust.add(subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));

                    Log.i("Description", subMenuObject.getString("Description"));
                    description.add(subMenuObject.getString("Description"));


                    extraDescription.add(subMenuObject.getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity").getJSONObject(j).getString("Description"));{

                    }
                }

            }
            crustSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_crust);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterCru = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, crust);
            dataAdapterCru
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            crustSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterCru);

            sizeSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_pizza_size);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterDes = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, description);
            dataAdapterDes
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sizeSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterDes);

          extraDescriptionOneSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_extratoppingone);
          ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterExtraDesOne = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, extraDescription);
          dataAdapterExtraDesOne
          .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          extraDescriptionOneSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterExtraDesOne);

          extraDescriptionTwoSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_extratoppingtwo);
          ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterExtraDesTwo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, extraDescription);
          dataAdapterExtraDesTwo
          .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
          extraDescriptionTwoSP.setAdapter(dataAdapterExtraDesTwo);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please post your log cat file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you were doing wrong**

Description actually is a json object and hence should be accessed using a json object.

From that json object you fetch the String.
Replace the highlighted portion with this
[image]

```
    JSONArray  extraItemEntityArray = subMenuobject.getJsonArray("ExtraItemEntity");

             for(int i=0;i< extraItemEntityArray.length();i++){
                 String extraItemdescription=extraItemEntityArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Description");

                description.add(extraItemdescription);

Log.i("Description from array", extraItemdescription);   
             }       
Log.i("Description",subMenuObject.getString("Description"));
```

**How to do it right**

//Fetch the array containing the objects

```
JSONArray extraItemEntity = object.getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity");
```

//Fetch a particular object from the array above.

```
JSONObject extraItemObject = extraItemEntity
                            .getJSONObject(i);
```

//Now retrieve the description as a string from the chosen object(above).

```
String description = extraItemObject.getString("Description");
```

Comment: Can u upload the complete code please. This gives me errors. other thing is how can i pass the string to an array

Comment: See now ... if you get it now ?

Comment: can u check my Updated code section please. Now it loads items but after 2 iterations it goes to exception. because of that it loads only 2 items

Comment: can you post your exception log ?

Comment: Check the update and replace the highlighted code with the new one.

Comment: Im getting an error for jsonArray in String extraItemdescription = jsonArray
         .getJSONObject(i).getString("Description");

Comment: Replace jsonArray with extraItemEntityArray...updated that in the answer as well..

Comment: Still the same, now it loads the items inside the last array. once it done its goes into exception. so 1st 2 arrays doesn't load all the items. I had to change i into k in the line for(int i=0;i< extraItemEntityArray.length();i++){...

Comment: Yes...but obvious because you are using that already in the loop scope..I wrote a code to extract the description .. So such changes which are very specific ..Change them accordingly

Comment: Now this loads only this loop, once this is done it goes into exception. (int k = 0; k < extraItemEntityArray.length(); k++). because of that it doesnt load all the items in for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {

Comment: What's the exception now?

Comment: updated the print screen.. its going to exception  when passing the extraDescription.add(subMenuObject.getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity").getJSONObject(j).getString("Description"));

Comment: There seems to be an extra curly brace near the extraDescription.add line... And post the exception that you are getting... Because code seems ok

Comment: it perfectly works now when i remove this line extraDescription.add(subMenuObject
        .getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity")
        .getJSONObject(j).getString("Description"));

Comment: that is the screen shot i have posted in my question. I have small problem can u take a look at this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757682/issue-with-android-spinners-loading-distinct-values-in-spinners?noredirect=1#comment45796505_28757682

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71847/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-john-david).

Answer (score 0):

ExtraItemEntity Array is inside SubMenuEntity Array.

So, you can find it as below..

```
JSONArray subMenuArray = object.getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");
                for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
                    JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray
                            .getJSONObject(j);
                    Log.i("Crust", subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));
                    crust.add(subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));

                    Log.i("Description", subMenuObject.getString("Description"));
                    description.add(subMenuObject.getString("Description"));

                    JSONArray subExtraItemEntity = object.getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity");
                    for (int k = 0; j < subExtraItemEntity.length(); ++j) {
                    JSONObject subExtraItemObject = subExtraItemEntity
                            .getJSONObject(k);

                    Log.i("ExtraItemEntity Description", subExtraItemObject.getString("Description"));
                    description.add(subExtraItemObject.getString("Description"));
                } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray extraItemEntity = object.getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity");
JSONObject extraItemObject = extraItemEntity.getJSONObject(i);
String description = extraItemObject.getString("Description");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do this :
 for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

    if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
            && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("1")) {

        JSONArray subMenuArray = object.getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");
        for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
            JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray
                    .getJSONObject(j);
            Log.i("Crust", subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));
            crust.add(subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));

            subMenuObject.getString("Description"));
            description.add(subMenuObject.getString("Description"));

         if(subMenuObject.get("ExtraItemEntity") instanceof JSONArray){
             JSONArray  jsonArray=subMenuobject.getJsonArray("ExtraItemEntity");

         for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
             String extraItemdescription=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Description");
         }

         }

        }

    }
```